# How to add a border to a shape in Adobe Photoshop CS2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics-editing

How do I add a border to a simple shape in Adobe Photoshop CS2? I'm creating a polygon that is white; I want it to have a black border.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply a 1px stroke 0% fill *style* to the polygon.

You should find that under Window->Styles Menu.